# extract pdf using pdfminer with whitespace

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer, pypdf

I am trying to extract text from pdf, which is discussed in SO multiple times, but still I am unable to extract pdf, retaining the whitespaces between words.

```
$python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2016, 11:28:32) 
[GCC 6.2.1 20160901 (Red Hat 6.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyPDF2
>>> pdfFileObj = open('/var/tmp/acs%2Eaccounts%2E6b00452.pdf','rb')
>>> pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
>>> pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
>>> pageObj.extractText()
```

Which is yeilding:

> 'TowardtheRationalDesignofNovelNoncentrosymmetricMaterials:\nFactorsIn\nuencingtheFrameworkStructures\nKangMinOk\n*DepartmentofChemistry,Chung-AngUniversity,84Heukseok-ro,Dongjak-gu,Seoul06974,RepublicofKorea\nCONSPECTUS:Solid-statematerialswithextendedstructureshaverevealed\nmanyinterestingstructure-relatedch\naracteristics.Amongmany,materials\ncrystallizinginnoncentrosymmetric(NCS)spacegroupshaveattractedmassive\n\nattentionattributabletoavarietyofsuperbfunctionalpropertiessu

but, if I use `pdf2txt.py` directly in terminal, I am getting:

```
$pdf2txt.py '/var/tmp/acs%2Eaccounts%2E6b00452.pdf'| more
```

I am getting the output:

> Article
>
> pubs.acs.org/accounts
>
> Toward the Rational Design of Novel Noncentrosymmetric Materials:
>   Factors Inﬂuencing the Framework Structures
>
> Kang Min Ok*
>
> Department of Chemistry, Chung-Ang University, 84 Heukseok-ro,
>   Dongjak-gu, Seoul 06974, Republic of Korea
>
> CONSPECTUS: Solid-state materials with extended structures have
>   revealed many interesting structure-related characteristics. Among
>   many, materials crystallizing in noncentrosymmetric (NCS) space groups
>   have attracted massive attention attributable to a variety of superb
>   functional properties su

which is the desired output.

I am not getting what I am doing wrong in my python script.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Met the same problem. Solved by looking deeper into the `pdf2txt.py` script.

I bet `pdf2txt.py` is from `pdfMiner` ( `pdfMiner.six` for python3 ).

You should add the parameters in `pdfminer.layout.LAParams()`.

```
if not no_laparams:
    laparams = pdfminer.layout.LAParams()
    for param in ("all_texts", "detect_vertical", "word_margin", "char_margin", "line_margin", "boxes_flow"):
        paramv = locals().get(param, None)
        if paramv is not None:
            setattr(laparams, param, paramv)
else:
    laparams = None
```

To learn more about the parameters. Take a look at [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfminer-users/KWGdoZ5-G04).

Comment: Facing the same issue. How to override the params?

Comment: I don't know how this solution works, it it indeed works. Thanks a lot! With `no_laparams=False`, provide the `laparams` to `TextConverter` i.e. `TextConverter(.., laparams=laparams)`